# How to treat a mixed manyTomany and oneTomany tables in a servlet

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, servlets

I am building a web application project with maven,
hibernate h2, servlet, and jsp, my doubt is, should I pass something
in the 'Usuario' and 'collection' place (i have filled that fields as
 'null' but i don't know if it is correct)? How can i associate the
 users with events and 'asiste' table?  The teachers gave me the scheme
 and they don't explain anithing more, so i don't know how to treat the
 database into the servlets, for example, one user create one or more
 events and can asists to the events and if the user suscribe in a
 event must pay. Sorry for my english, i hope you can give me a hand
 guys

> [The structure mvc (i have one servlet per jsp)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ze9i.png)
>
> [The scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxl2f.jpg)
>
> Pojo Asiste:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "asistentes")
@AssociationOverrides({
        @AssociationOverride(name = "primaryKey.usuario", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idUsuario")),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "primaryKey.evento", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idEvento")) })
public class Asiste {

    // clave primaria-id compuesta

    private UsuarioEventoId primaryKey = new UsuarioEventoId();

    // campos adicionales
    @Column(name = "nombreEntidad")
    private String nombreEntidad;

    @Column(name = "nombreCuenta")
    private String nombreCuenta;

    @Column(name = "iban")
    private String iban;

    @Column(name = "numeroCuenta")
    private String numeroCuenta;

    @Column(name = "fechaPago")
    //@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Type(type="date")
    private Date fechaPago;
```

> Pojo Evento:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "eventos")
public class Evento {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "idEvento")
    private long idEvento;

    @Column(name = "nombreEvento")
    private String nombreEvento;

    @Column(name = "tipoEvento")
    private String tipoEvento;

    @Column(name = "descripcionEvento")
    private String descripcionEvento;

    @Column(name = "precioEvento")
    private double precioEvento;

    @Column(name = "fechaCreacion")
    private Date fechaCreacion;

    @Column(name = "fechaCelebracion")
    @Type(type="date")
    private Date fechaCelebracion;

    // Los días que faltan para que se cumpla el evento
    @Column(name = "diasRestantes")
    private long diasRestantes;

    @Column(name = "iva")
    private double iva;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "usuario_id")
    private Usuario usuario;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "primaryKey.evento",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    @ElementCollection(targetClass=Integer.class)
    private Collection<Asiste> listadoAsistentes;
```

> Pojo Usuario:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usuarios")
public class Usuario {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "idUsuario")
    private long idUsuario;

    @Column(name = "nombreUsuario")
    private String nombreUsuario;

    @Column(name = "apellidosUsuario")
    private String apellidosUsuario;

    @Column(name = "contrasenia")
    private String contrasenia;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "administrador")
    private boolean administrador;

    @Column(name = "preguntaSecreta")
    private String preguntaSecreta;

    @Column(name = "respuestaSecreta")
    private String respuestaSecreta;

    // ¿Sería lo adecuado?
    @Column(name = "sexo")
    private String sexo;

    // Primera relación 1 a * con la tabla Evento
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="usuario",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @ElementCollection(targetClass=Integer.class)
    private Collection<Evento> listadoEventos;

    // Relación de 1 a * con la tabla Asiste
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "primaryKey.usuario",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    @ElementCollection(targetClass=Integer.class)
    private Collection<Asiste> listadoAsistentes;
```

> Pojo UsuarioEventoId (embeddable class)

```
@Embeddable
public class UsuarioEventoId implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    private Usuario usuario;


    private Evento evento;

    // Getters y Setters
    @ManyToOne
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    public Usuario getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }
    @ManyToOne
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    public Evento getEvento() {
        return evento;
    }

    public void setEvento(Evento evento) {
        this.evento = evento;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UsuarioEventoId [usuario=" + usuario + ", evento=" + evento + "]";
    }
```

> Servlet form Usuario

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        String nombreUsuario = request.getParameter("nombreUsuario");
        String apellidosUsuario = request.getParameter("apellidosUsuario");
        String contrasenia = request.getParameter("contrasenia");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String preguntaSecreta = request.getParameter("preguntaSecreta");
        String respuestaSecreta = request.getParameter("respuestaSecreta");
        String sexo = request.getParameter("sexo");

        GestionUsuarios gestionUsuarios = new GestionUsuarios();

        // No tengo muy claro si con los campos a null funcionará correctamente
        // cuando se agreguen los objetos a la lista
        Usuario usuario = new Usuario(nombreUsuario, apellidosUsuario, contrasenia, email, false, preguntaSecreta,
                respuestaSecreta, sexo, null, null);

        gestionUsuarios.addUsuario(usuario);

        request.setAttribute("usuarios", gestionUsuarios.list());

        //response.sendRedirect("app/tablaUsuarios.jsp");

        //response.sendRedirect("app/tablaUsuarios.jsp");
        //Había que tener aquí un dispather para que la tabla se mostrara
        request.getRequestDispatcher("tablaUsuarios.jsp").forward(request, response);


    }
```

> Event form Servlet

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse    response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // doGet(request, response);

        String nombreEvento = request.getParameter("nombreEvento");
        String tipoEvento = request.getParameter("tipoEvento");
        String descripcionEvento = request.getParameter("descripcionEvento");
        // Hacer el parseDouble
        String precioEvento = request.getParameter("precioEvento");

        double precioParseado = 0;
        try {
            precioParseado = Double.parseDouble(precioEvento);
        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {

        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {

        }

        // Fecha de creación: debe aparecer automáticamente
        Date fechaCreacion = new Date();

        // Fecha de celebración
        String fechaCeleb = request.getParameter("fechaCelebracion");

        DateFormat formatoFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date fechaCelebracion = null;
        try {
            fechaCelebracion = formatoFecha.parse(fechaCeleb);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // De momento los días restantes estarán a null hasta que me de tiempo a
        // implementarlo(resta de fechas)
        String iva = request.getParameter("iva");

        double ivaParseado = 0;
        try {
            ivaParseado = Double.parseDouble(iva);
        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {

        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {

        }

        GestionEventos gestionEventos = new GestionEventos();



        Evento evento = new Evento(nombreEvento, tipoEvento, descripcionEvento, precioParseado, fechaCreacion,
                fechaCelebracion, 0, ivaParseado, null, null);


        gestionEventos.addEvento(evento);

        request.setAttribute("eventos", gestionEventos.list());

        request.getRequestDispatcher("tabla.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }
```

> and Asiste form Servlet

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        String nombreEntidad = request.getParameter("nombreEntidad");
        String nombreCuenta = request.getParameter("nombreCuenta");
        String iban = request.getParameter("iban");
        String numeroCuenta = request.getParameter("numeroCuenta");
        Date fechaPago = new Date();


        GestionAsistentes gestionAsistentes = new GestionAsistentes();

        // No tengo muy claro si con los campos a null funcionará correctamente
        // cuando se agreguen los objetos a la lista
        Asiste asistente = new Asiste(nombreEntidad, nombreCuenta, iban, numeroCuenta, fechaPago);

        gestionAsistentes.addAsistente(asistente);

        request.setAttribute("asistentes", gestionAsistentes.list());

        //response.sendRedirect("app/tablaUsuarios.jsp");

        //response.sendRedirect("app/tablaUsuarios.jsp");
        //Había que tener aquí un dispather para que la tabla se mostrara
        request.getRequestDispatcher("tablaAsiste.jsp").forward(request, response);


    }
```

Comment: To ease translation, have you considered http://es.stackoverflow.com/ ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, there are more users here so that's why i came